# How to do cross multiplication in neon?

Tags: simd, neon, armv7

Now, I have two 8bit arrays

One is

```
A[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Another is

```
B[2] = {1,2}
```

What I want to calculate is that:

```
C = A x B = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} x {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2} = {1,4,3,8,5,12,7,16}
```

How to do this using armv7 simd 
efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Define B as B[8] = {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2} and use vld1_u8 and vmul_u8.

Comment: How to define B as {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2} ？Here i need the cross load and the duplication, and that's the point.